# Git - switch merged branch

Tags: git, github

Using git locally, I merged from branch D into branch M.  But what I want is branch M merged into D. That is, I want to set D to become the active branch and have it reflect the merge.  I tried to set the current branch to D based on suggestions in this question: [Make an existing Git branch track a remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch)

```
git push -u origin D

error: failed to push some refs to 'url'
```

New to git and not sure if I'm barking up the right tree.  Ideally, I'd also like to leave M origin as-was (i.e. not push the merge to it).

Answer (score 0):

1. Discard merge commit, could be done [as answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/927386/6917446).
2. Execute `git checkout D`.
3. Execute `git merge M`.
4. Push M branch to another remote branch, so origin M branch will be not upstream branch anymore, like `git push -u origin M-modified`.